# Making numbers and then find duplicate numbers in the String + Counting valid Strings

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop, count

So I am making a method that fills up a String with numbers from 10000 to 55555. The numbers are in the 6 number system. Meaning that when we have 10005, next number is 10010, and 11555 -> 12000. 
After I have filled up the String, I shall loop through the String and count every number in the String which has only 2 or less equal digits (or count every number ,and remove those with 3 and more equal digits from the count).

I made a for-loop that fills up the String with all the numbers, but I don't figure out how to find the numbers with 3 og more equal digits. 
I'll guess I need another for-loop with an If-statement, but I just don't figure it out. Tried to use both char and int for looping through, but I obviously do something wrong.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class TestProgram {
public static void main(String... args)
{
    System.out.println(membersnumbers());
}

public static int membersnumbers()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1296; i < 7776; i++) //fills the String with numbers from 1000 to 5555
    {                                  //without numbers over 6
        String number = Integer.toString(i,6); //making the String and fills it with numbers  

        for (<run through all the numbers>)
        {
            if (<number has less than 3 equal digits )
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }  
    return count;
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will need two additional for loops, one for iterating over the characters in the string and one for counting equal characters.

```
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
   char curChar = string.charAt(i);
   int charCount = 0;
   for(int j = 0; j < string.length(); j++){
      if(j != i && curChar == string.charAt(j)) charCount++;
    }
   if(count >= 3) count++;
   charCount = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if you showed us what you have tried so far. Here is my slightly crazy implementation (ab)using streams.

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

public static long membersnumbers() {
    return IntStream.range(1296, 7776)
            .mapToObj(integer -> Integer.toString(integer, 6))
            .filter(string -> string.chars()
                    .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(groupingBy(identity()))
                    .values()
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(list -> list.size() > 1))
            .count();
}
```

Try extracting parts of your code into meaningful methods that split the problem into smaller ones, for example:

```
public static int membersnumbers() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1296; i < 7776; i++) {
        if (hasAtLeastTwoSameCharacters(Integer.toString(i, 6))) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

At this point you shouldn't worry about how `hasAtLeastTwoSameCharacters` works. Just define next smaller step that that you need.

```
private static boolean hasAtLeastTwoSameCharacters(String string) {
    for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
        if (countCharactersInString(c, string) > 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here again, don't worry about `countCharactersInString`, just replace the problem with the smaller one until you get "problem" so small that you can easily solve it in a single method.

```
private static int countCharactersInString(char characterToCount, String string) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == characterToCount) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

PS Leave the opening bracket `{` at the end of line - it drastically reduces a risk of adding a semicolon at the end of line. It may take a long time to figure out why the condition in code below doesn't work:

```
if (1 == 2);
{
    System.out.println("should be never printed but always is");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your loops are nested wrongly - you're running through all the numbers in the loop body where you're creating each one.

You should do either:

```
for (int i = 1296; i < 7776; i++) { //fills the String with numbers from 1000 to 5555
                                    //without numbers over 6
    String number = Integer.toString(i,6); //making the String and fills it with numbers  
    <store number in some array/collection>
}

for (<run through all the numbers>) {
    if (<number has less than 3 equal digits>) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

or just this, since you don't need to store the numbers:

```
for (int i = 1296; i < 7776; i++) { //fills the String with numbers from 1000 to 5555
                                    //without numbers over 6
    String number = Integer.toString(i,6); //making the String and fills it with numbers  

    if (<number has less than 3 equal digits>) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Regarding the method to test the digits, you can do something like this:

```
boolean hasLessThan3EqualDigits(String number) {

    int[] digitCount = new int[6]; // counters for digits 0 1 2 3 4 5

    for (<run through the characters (digits) in the string 'number'>) {
        <increase the corresponding digitCount element>
    }

    int maxEqualDigits = <find maximum value in digitCount>

    return maxEqualDigits < 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following method to get max number of same letter in a string -

```
public static int getMaxCount(String s) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            Integer val = map.get(new Character(c));
            if(val != null){
                map.put(c, new Integer(val + 1));
            } else {
                map.put(c,1);
            }
        }

        List<Integer> countList = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
        Collections.sort(countList);
        Collections.reverse(countList);
        return countList.get(0);
    }
```

call this method in your loop where you are iterating over numbers as string, and check if this method returns greater than equals to 3 to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
public static int findDuplicateDitigs(String str){

    int occurrence = 0;
    Map<Character, Integer> dupMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    char[] chrs = str.toCharArray();
    for(Character ch:chrs){
        if(dupMap.containsKey(ch)){
            dupMap.put(ch, dupMap.get(ch)+1);
        } else {
            dupMap.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }
    Set<Character> keys = dupMap.keySet();
    for(Character ch:keys){
        if(dupMap.get(ch) > 1){
            occurrence = dupMap.get(ch);
        }
    }
    return occurrence;
}
```

in main:

```
List<String> listNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1296; i < 7776; i++) //fills the String with numbers from 1000 to 5555
    {                                  //without numbers over 6
        String number = Integer.toString(i,6); //making the String and fills it with numbers  
        listNumber.add(number);
    }  
    List<String> newListNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s : listNumber)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        counter = findDuplicateDitigs(s);
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            newListNumber.add(s);
        }
    }
    for(String s : newListNumber)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

This is part of output:

> 32540
>
> 32541
>
> 34012
>
> 34015
>
> 34021
>
> 34025
>
> 34051
>
> 34052
>
> 34152